# Android Firebase CacheExpiration set to zero?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

In my app, my user need to retrieve a string at 2pm every day from remote config, I set the `CacheExpiration` to zero to retrieve immediately. Is that possible there will be throttling if I have many users? if there is throttling, will it return "Task.isSuccessful" or "fail"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throttling only happens when the client actually exceeds the [rate limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37910758/how-is-the-firebase-remote-config-rate-limit-counted) for fetch requests, regardless of configuration.  If you only fetch every day at a certain time on each users' device, that will not be a problem.

If your code is rate limited, the Task (on Android) will fail with an appropriate message in the exception.

Comment: I decided to use database real time rest api to get the string