# About Firebase Remote Configuration limitations

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

We'll start to new project using the Firebase.

First of all, I'll try to set static like app version) to remote config to check the lower version in app-side.

So, I'd try to search the limitation/quota of the 'firebase remote configuration' such as traffic, connections, concurrent connections per month and so on, but I can't find any documents about Firebase remote configurations.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is the Firebase Remote Config rate limit counted?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37910758/how-is-the-firebase-remote-config-rate-limit-counted)

Comment: Possibly helpful links: https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/#policies_and_limits, https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/parameters#limits_on_parameters_and_conditions

Comment: Is there any other limitations about traffic or concurrent connections ? above documents are limitations about the number of parameters and length of parameter.

Comment: I've actually searched for something like that (specifically in the [Pricings page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/)), but there isn't anything explicitly mentioned in the documentations.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41097686/dynamically-change-values-of-colors-xml-to-change-look-and-feel-of-android-app/41097789#41097789

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There aren't really any official public numbers, partly because the team reserves the right to change them in the future to better suit the needs of the service.

That said, Remote Config is designed to be free for your apps, no matter how popular they become. You shouldn't ever have to worry about concurrent connections or connections per month or anything like that, as long as your client behaves reasonably.

What does that mean? Well, personally, my recommendation would be to not set your cache for anything less than 3 hours. If you need something faster than that, then you should really start looking into the Realtime Database. Otherwise, you should be find with Remote Config.