# How is the Firebase Remote Config throttling rate limit counted?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I have searched this question in stackoverflow and got an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37910758/how-is-the-firebase-remote-config-rate-limit-counted) that it's countered individually. However, I noticed that in firebase document "thousands of test users" is mentioned which made me fell uncertain about the previous answer.[image]

Besides, when I checked the source code I found that the Http code is checked when decide to throttle or not, as:

```
private boolean shouldThrottle(BackoffMetadata backoffMetadata, int httpStatusCode) {
return backoffMetadata.getNumFailedFetches() > 1 || httpStatusCode == HTTP_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS;}
```

Maybe the firebase server will count the total request of each project but not each device, and the HTTP_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS may be just a huge number that can't be triggered simply by testing in several phones but can be triggered by thousands of test users. I'm not sure about it and can not verify it either. If you have any idea, please commit here, thanks!

Comment: Seems it counts how many requests are being sent from each device. Because it is guaranteed that remote config is free despite of the numbers of users. What exactly do you want to achieve? Seems you will not be able to make it realtime, but in my case it is possible to fetch it in 15 minutes. I guess it is nearly maximum what is allowed.

Comment: @Leo Droidcoder I wish to make a request every time the app is opened. It's not that frequent but I want the cache be invalid when firebase config is updated, so I call fetch(0) to set the cache time to zero and if throttling is triggered the default value defined in-app is used. If throttling is triggered by all users, it might keep throttling for most of time.

Comment: "every time the app is opened" Do you mean one app is created or moves to foreground?

Comment: "want the cache be invalid when firebase config is updated" I am afraid there is no way to get triggered on this

Comment: @Leo Droidcoder "open app" here means app cold boost that the app is not in the background, and there is an initTask in app which can run the request code to fetch data when app is opened. Since "fetch(0)" set the cache interval to 0, the app will get new data if it's not throttled, or get nothing if  throttled. It's exactly what I what to express.

Comment: Looks like your approach is one of the advised approaches and these requests should not be throttled. Have you experienced any throttlings?

Comment: @Leo Droidcoder Yes, I put the requset function into a for loop and it can be observed that after 60 requests any new request will be blocked for obout 2 to 3 minutes.

Comment: Why do yo put the request function into a loop? You should call it once. Or alternatively, implement some extra logic to fetch it again after some period of time (at least 15 minutes).

Comment: @LeonidUstenko regarding your comment "Because it is guaranteed that remote config is free despite of the numbers of users.", are there some links to that, to make it clear? IHMO there should be some quota, what if I have millions of users. Even if they send one request per 12 hours it's still a great amount of requests.